# Some general questions about live notifications/alerts

Tags: javascript, ajax, notifications, alert

I was wondering if those `notifications/alerts` (for example on `twitchalerts`, most of lifestreamers use it) created in `js/ajax` or some other language?

Also is there any framework for that lang, that could make creating something like this easier?

And last thing, is it necessary to use some kind of `listening application`? Or it can be somehow created built in to web page?

Thank you for answers. And if someone wants to know, I'm kind of new in web programming and just curious how things like this are created :) for learning purposes.

Thank you again! :)

Comment: Any one? At last a tip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two ways of doing it:
One is to have a simple html/css element to popup inside the page that tells you something, there's many libraries for that. Example: http://bootstrap-notify.remabledesigns.com/

Advantages: easy to implement
Disadvantages: Doesn't show if the browser or tab is closed.

The other way is using the desktop notifications api: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/notifications/quick/

Advantages: Shows even if the browser is closed
Disadvantages: asks the user for permission, browser support http://caniuse.com/#search=notification

Comment: Thank you very much :) I meant something like first solution. Tab would be opened all the time because it is added as a source in streaming application :) thanks again!